# What is the "let" keyword in functional languages like F# and OCaml for?

Tags: f#, ocaml, functional-programming

When looking at F#, Ocaml and other functional language code examples I notice that the let keyword is used very often.

- Why do you need it? Why were the languages designed to have it?
- Why can't you just leave it out? e.g: let x=4 becomes x=4

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In F# (and OCaml) `let` is quite powerful construct that is used for *value binding*, which means assigning some meaning to a symbol. This can mean various things:

**Declaring local or global value** - you can use it for declaring local values. This is similar to creating a variable in imperative languages, with the exception that the value of the variable cannot be changed later (it is immutable):

```
let hello = "Hello world"
printfn "%s" hello
```

**Declaring function** - you can also use it for declaring functions. In this case you specify that a symbol is a function with some arity:

```
let add a b = a + b
printfn "22 + 20 = %d" (add 22 20)
```

**Why do you need it?** In F#, the code would be ambiguous without it. You can use *value hiding* to create new symbol that hides the previous symbol (with the same name), so for example the following returns `true`:

```
let test () =
  let x = 10
  let x = 20 // hides previous 'x'
  x = 20     // compares 'x' with 20 and returns result
```

If you omitted the `let` keyword, you wouldn't know whether you're comparing values or whether you're declaring a new symbol. Also, as noted by others, you can use the `let <symbol> = <expression> in <expression>` syntax (if you use line-break in F#, then you don't need `in`) to write value bindings as part of another expression:

```
let z = (let x = 3 + 3 in x * x)
```

Here, the value of `z` will be 36. Although you may be able to invent some syntax that doesn't require the `let` keyword, I think that using `let` simply makes the code more readable.

Comment: It seems that `let` is introduced only because `x = y` is ambiguous? If `==` is used for comparison then does the `let` becomes unnecessary?

Comment: @KennyTM: In principle, you could definitely invent some non-ambiguous syntax, but I think that `let` is quite readable. Also, in the full syntax, the `let` is coupled with `in` (because it is an expression - there are no statements in F#), so you'd need something similar.

Comment: I shiver when I see `let` w/out `in` in F#... As an ocaml programmer I see the `in` being a huge help in readability and formatting. Why is it not used as much by F# programmers?

Comment: @nlucaroni You can use the OCaml 'in' syntax in F# by omitting the "#light" option at the beginning of the file.
F# designers thought ocaml syntax a little verbose and gave users the option to have a #light-er one. Scope in #light syntax is given by indentation. When you get used to it it's pretty nice :-)

Answer (score 9):

The main purpose of "let" is putting a scope around its definitions.

`let <definitions> in <expression>`

Makes sure that the definitions don't pollute the namespace of anything other than `<expression>`.

Answer (score 4):

"let" introduces a new variable scope, and allows you to bind variables to values for that scope. It is often read as "let x be [value] in ...". When you don't have assignment, it is very useful to avoid conflicting variable names.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell,

```
foo = let x = 5
      y = 7
      in z=x+y
```

is used to make clear that x and y are "private" variables to foo.

Comment: But in F# you need to write `let foo = ...` even for non-local variables.

Answer (score 1):

let means "bind value to name" and generally spoken, creates a new variable.
`x = 4` means "assign 4 to x", which doesn't create a new name.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233238.aspx

Comment: Might be traditional from Lisp, where they don't use `=` and infix syntax in general.

Comment: Actually in both F# and ocaml `x = 4` is a boolean operation that returns true iff x is equal to 4. It's not assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're into learning, [this lecture](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs3110/2009sp/lectures/lec06.html) might be relevant also, esp. the part about evaluating the let term.