# immutable in F#

Tags: f#, immutability, shadowing

I know that variables in F# are immutable by default.
But, for example in F# interactive:

```
  > let x = 4;;

val x : int = 4

> let x = 5;;

val x : int = 5

> x;;
val it : int = 5
>
```

So, I assign 4 to x, then 5 to x and it's changing. Is it correct? Should it give some error or warning? Or I just don't understand how it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844047/what-is-the-let-keyword-in-functional-languages-like-f-and-ocaml-for .  The answers there explain the distinction between variable binding and variable assignment.

Comment: @Alex: You may find the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478079/f-shadowing-and-nested-function) helpful.

Comment: The question is similar but it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you write `let x = 3`, you are binding the identifier `x` to the value `3`. If you do that a second time in the same scope, you are declaring a new identifier that hides the previous one since it has the same name.

Mutating a value in F# is done via the destructive update operator, `<-`. This will fail for immutable values, i.e.:

```
> let x = 3;;

val x : int = 3

> x <- 5;;

  x <- 5;;
  ^^^^^^

stdin(2,1): error FS0027: This value is not mutable
```

To declare a mutable variable, add `mutable` after `let`:

```
let mutable x = 5;;

val mutable x : int = 5

> x <- 6;;
val it : unit = ()
> x;;
val it : int = 6
```

But what's the difference between the two, you might ask? An example may be enough:

```
let i = 0;
while i < 10 do
    let i = i + 1
    ()
```

Despite the appearances, this is an infinite loop. The `i` declared inside the loop is a different `i` that hides the outer one. The outer one is immutable, so it always keeps its value `0` and the loop never ends. The correct way to write this is with a mutable variable:

```
let mutable i = 0;
while i < 10 do
    i <- i + 1
    ()
```

Answer (score 5):

`x` is not changed, it's just hidden by next declaration.
For example:

```
> let x = 4;;
val x : int = 4
> let x = "abc";;
val x : string = "abc"
>
```

Comment: What is difference between hidden and immutable? Does it mean that I still can get previous value of x?

Comment: @Alex see my answer for an explanation of the difference.

Answer (score 4):

You're not assigning 5 to `x`, you are defining a new variable.

The following example shows that there are two distinct variables.
(It also shows that you can "access" the old x if it is in a closure, used by another function):

```
let x = 5;;
let f y = y+x;;
f 10;;
let x = 0;;
f 10;;
```

yields

```
>
val x : int = 5

>
val f : int -> int
> val it : int = 15
>
val x : int = 0

> val it : int = 15
```

as you see, both calls to f use the first variable `x`. The definition `let x = 0;;` defines a new variable `x`, but does not redefines `f`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a minimal example illustrating identifier "shadowing" (i.e. hiding) in F#:

```
let x = 0
do //introduce a new lexical scope
    let x = 1 //"shadow" (i.e. hide) the previous definition of x
    printfn "%i" x //prints 1
//return to outer lexical scope
printfn "%i" x //prints 0, proving that our outer definition of x was not mutated by our inner definition of x
```

Your example is actually a bit more complex, because you are working in the F# Interactive (FSI). FSI dynamically emits code that looks something like the following in your example:

```
module FSI_0001 =
    let x = 4;;

open FSI_0001 //x = 4 is now available in the top level scope
module FSI_0002 =
    let x = 5;;

open FSI_0002 //x = 5 is now available in the top level scope, hiding x = 4
module FSI_0003 =
    let it = x;;

open FSI_0003
//... subsequent interactions
```