# trying to understand a clojure "let" example

Tags: clojure

```
(defn make-adder [x]
  (let [y x]
    (fn [z] (+ y z))))
(def add2 (make-adder 2))
(add2 4)
-> 6
```

I am trying to figure out this let example in clojure.  What is the y variable it never seems to be set to anything.  I do not understand the let syntax.

Comment: It's binding `y` to `x`.

Comment: ah duh thanks makes sense now

Comment: A pedantic point, y is not a variable for its value cannot ever vary. There are `vars` in Clojure, but they are rarely used in let bindings (`defn` here creates a var named `make-adder`, and it and `add2` are the only variables shown here).

Comment: This code example is actually from https://clojure.org/about/functional_programming; last code snippet under "First-class functions"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
(let [y x]
    <body>)
```

evaluates `<body>` in a lexical context where `y` is bound to the value of `x`.

See the Clojure [documentation](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28let%20%5Bbindings*%20%5D%20exprs*%29) for the description of `let` syntax. The general form is:

```
(let [sym1 val1
      sym2 val2
      sym3 val3
      ... ]
    <body>)
```

Each `symN` is bound to the corresponding `valN`.

Comment: A nitpick: your naming here is misleading, unless a valN is of type var, no varN is a var.

Comment: Thanks, that's a difference between Lisp and Clojure I wasn't aware of. I've updated my answer to use `symN` instead.

Answer (score 11):

This function:

```
(defn make-adder [x]
  (let [y x]
    (fn [z] (+ y z))))
```

Itself returns a [first-class function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) (a function that can be returned, passed around and assigned to a name just like any other value). Inside the `let`, `x` is bound to `y`, and so the function above is equivalent to this function below:

```
(defn make-adder [x]
  (fn [z] (+ x z)))
```

So that when `make-adder` is called with the value `2`, it returns this first-class function:

```
(fn [z] (+ 2 z))
```

Remember, a first-class function can be assigned to a name, as in this line:

```
(def add2 (made-adder 2))
```

The line above is therefore equivalent to this code:

```
(def add2 (fn [z] (+ 2 z)))
```

And so is equivalent to this code also:

```
(defn add2 [z] (+ 2 z))
```

Which means that when `add2` is called:

```
(add2 4)
```

The expression above evaluates to this:

```
(+ 2 4)
```

Which evaluates to `6`.

Comment: Nice, detailed answer, but 90% of it has nothing to do with his question, which was just about `y`.

Comment: True. I wanted to fully explain the example.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the answer. I came to SO because the documentation wasn't doing it for me, and although the `let` explanation was lacking here, this is a very good explanation of the non-`let` stuff in the code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let expression is standard in many functional programming languages. 
[What is the "let" keyword in functional languages like F# and OCaml for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844047/what-is-the-let-keyword-in-functional-languages-like-f-and-ocaml-for)