# F# value shadowing - is it possible to disable value shadowing within the same scope

Tags: f#, shadowing

I spoted a bug in my own code because of copy/paste. The same value name is shadowned by the copy/pasted in the same scope.

```
let func() =
    let a = 1
    let a = something_else
    ....
```

In C# I wont pass compile. is there a way to disable shadowing? at least within the same level of scope?

Thanks

Comment: No, this is not possible

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844047/what-is-the-let-keyword-in-functional-languages-like-f-and-ocaml-for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't disable shadowing in F# -- it's an important language feature.

However, you *can* instruct the compiler to issue a warning or error which will help you catch cases of **accidental** shadowing.

In the project properties, add [`--warnon:1182`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx) to the "Other flags" textbox (on the Build tab, under the platform target dropdown). This triggers a compiler warning when you accidentally shadow a variable and cause it not to be used anywhere. If you'd rather these cases cause compilation to fail, you can also add `1182` to the "Specific warnings" textbox under the "Treat warnings as errors" section of the Build tab.

Finally -- do install the [Visual F# Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff) extension. It provides additional syntax highlighting functionality and will indicate unused variables so they're easy to spot in your code.

Comment: Thanks jack. That is exactly what I was after. I also noticed F# power pack grays out the value. On the other do you mind elaborate in this post why is shadowing important to F#? I am not sure what workflow has to be done by shadowing. It seems all the immutability security can easily be undone by shadowing ( I am aware shadowing is not mutation)